# Error : Index was outside the bounds of the array in Petapoco with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, petapoco

I have define ConnectionStringName and Namespace in Database.tt and using Petapoco 4.0.2 . But when i Save the Database.tt page then follwing error comes :

Error   1   Running transformation: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Array.InternalGetReference(Void* elemRef, Int32 rank, Int32* pIndices)
   at System.Array.GetValue(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingBCE09AF683DB0757ACB5E91651A283FE.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetCurrentProject()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingBCE09AF683DB0757ACB5E91651A283FE.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetConnectionString(String& connectionStringName, String& providerName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingBCE09AF683DB0757ACB5E91651A283FE.GeneratedTextTransformation.InitConnectionString()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingBCE09AF683DB0757ACB5E91651A283FE.GeneratedTextTransformation.LoadTables()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingBCE09AF683DB0757ACB5E91651A283FE.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.RunTransformation(TemplateProcessingSession session, String source, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, String& result)

Answer (score 0):

That's an old version you're using. Better support and bug fixes for T4 have been added in the newer version. Maybe [check it out](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PetaPoco/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was showing up because I had a typo in one of the table names.